# How should I create a unique id that isn't incremental?

Tags: php, hash, collision

For example, right now when I'm creating boards (agile), it will create a new board and its id will be n + 1.

What is an efficient way of creating an ID where there won't be any collision even if there are 1 billion+ entries? I'll be implementing this in PHP

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: You may be looking for a UUID/GUID. You haven't said what language you are using, but there will probably be a library to hand to generate those for you.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you on? I've done a bit of googling.: and there's a [com extension for Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) that provides GUID generation, and a [PECL one for Unix](http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid) (which provides the `uuid_create()` function).

As a PHP newbie, I am fairly gobsmacked there is still no native function to generate a GUID! I can remember looking at this briefly a decade or so ago and being surprised by it then. Some things don't progress, it seems.

Comment: Which is - for all intents and purposes - *nix. So try the PECL solution, I think.

Comment: Well, it looks like PHP has a native method uniqid and it creates the unique id based on the current time in microseconds.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php  and it's been around since php4

Comment: Hmm.. I have already several thousand entries in my db, I wonder if it would be worth it to encrypt the string based off of the incremental ID.  What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Yeah, the `uniqid()` approach would be fine. I got distracted by the mention of GUIDs, and as that's how I'd usually deal with this sort of thing, decided to investigate that line of thought.

Comment: Any reason to not simply leave the current IDs as is? Also, if you're gonna change from a numeric to a char column for your PK, I'd run some load testing & look if any performance tuning might be needed. I'm outa my depth with that sort of thing though... but I'm sure Google has the answers.

Comment: I would leave the ids as is for the sake of speed but users are complaining it's too easy to view other people's kanban board because the id is part of the url.